# How to work with SQL Views in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, sql-view, hana

I'm currently working on a project with Spring and HANA DB.

I have already an Webservice which is working properly, but I need to select a View from my HANA DB(created outside of the Spring Webservice).

My view is made from 2 tables, 4 of its fields are SUM of one column from one of the tables(which counts how much of each of each 4 possible values and shows that as a number in each of the 4 fields).

I read about in some Spring JPA posts that it should work properly with a simple select, my questions are:

I usually make selects like this:

```
TypedQuery<name_of_the_model_class> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM NameOfTheTable ORDER BY c.some_field DESC WHERE c.name =?1 ", name_of_the_model_class.class);
query.setParameter(1, name_to_search);
```

And then after that I just return the list to the Controller and the Controller shows that in a JSON.

The problem is, I have created this View in Eclipse, using directly SQL code in HANA DB, without creating it at the Webservice.

I would like to know, **is there a way to select like I showed above, returning it without a model class?** **It would just need a class with exactly the same fields like a model class but without @Entity annotation on it?**

OR **is there a way to create a view like a model class in Spring JPA? If there is a way, what are the annotations to make it work?**

**Spring JPA would not accept me to return it without a class would it?**

I read plenty posts but didn't found it, even in the Manual it doesn't give clear specification or examples.

Thanks a lot for your time, if I didn't explained it well pls tell me, I'm really stuck on this.

**More info(my latest try):**
My entire search function at the DAO:

```
public List<IncidentStatusResultsUser> getIncidentStatusByUser(String userID) throws ParseException {   

        List<IncidentStatusResultsUser> resultList = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM USERSTATUS ORDER BY c.uploadDateTime DESC WHERE c.userID=?1 ").setMaxResults(48).getResultList();


        Collections.reverse(resultList);

        return resultList;              
    }
```

I have created a class to just receive the data with the same fields of the view:

```
public class IncidentStatusResultsUser {

    private Date uploadDateTime ;
    private int status1;
    private int status2;
    private int status3;
    private int status4;

    //All gets and sets ommited
    public IncidentStatusResultsUser (Date uploadDateTime, long status1, long status2, long status3, long status4) {
    this.uploadDateTime = uploadDateTime;
    this.status1= status1;
    this.status2= status2;
    this.status3= status3;
    this.status4= status4;
    }


}
```

**EDIT-2: Added public constructor inside the class.**

Best Regards,
Famibica

Comment: You can just map a view direct to a spring jpa repository. If you really wanted you could write a viewrepository - but its unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to map your view to a JPA object as long as it has a primary key (or composite key). You can then map to a Spring JPA Reposiry so your query would go from -

```
TypedQuery<name_of_the_model_class> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM NameOfTheTable ORDER BY c.some_field DESC WHERE c.name =?1 ", name_of_the_model_class.class);
query.setParameter(1, name_to_search);
```

To

```
findBySomeFieldOrderBySomeFieldDesc(String name_to_search)
```

Comment: Can you explain in details please? I have just 3 months at Spring.

How would I change the entire SQL Query to just one simple function like you said? I usually do that in the controller, then the DAO makes the search and return the result to the controller.

You are saying that I need to create a JPA class to receive it anyway? A model? or is it another type?

I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

If you want JPA returning a list of object directly, you need a **DTO** just like the `IncidentStatusResultsUser` you created. make sure you have a `constructor` taking all fields, something like:

```
public IncidentStatusResultsUser(Date uploadDateTime, int status1, int status2, int status3, int status4)
```

Then in your query String `dtoQuery`, you can do:

```
SELECT new IncidentStatusResultsUser(c.uploadDateTime, c.status1,c.status2,c.status3,c.status4) 
FROM NameOfTheTable 
ORDER BY c.some_field DESC 
WHERE c.name =?1
```

Then you should be able to call your stuff:

```
List<IncidentStatusResultsUser> resultList = em.createQuery(dtoQuery).setMaxResults(48).getResultList();
```

Hope it works for you:)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but, how should I declare the DtoQuery, I need to create a constructor like this IncidentStatusResultsUser() right?

But where should I put: """"SELECT new IncidentStatusResultsUser(c.uploadDateTime, c.status1,c.status2,c.status3,c.status4) 
FROM NameOfTheTable 
ORDER BY c.some_field DESC 
WHERE c.name =?1""""

Thanks a lot!

Comment: DtoQuery is just a `String` I used to represent the long query. I assume em.createQuery accept String as what you have in your question.

Comment: Like this you mean? ------ List<IncidentStatusResultsUser> resultList = em.createQuery("SELECT new IncidentStatusResultsUser(c.uploadDateTime, c.InProgress,c.Handover,c.ActionNeeded,c.New) FROM USERSTATUS WHERE c.name =?1 ORDER BY c.uploadDateTime DESC").setParameter(1, userID).setMaxResults(48).getResultList(); ---- If it is like this had no success yet =( it gives me this error: ---- HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: ---Thanks!

Comment: this is an error when creating query? more details?  for setParameter, instead of question mark, try to use :userID in the query and set by setParameter("userID", userID);    AND what is your 'c' in the query? i assume you should put the 'c' after you table name!

Comment: The c is the way I usually do my searches on Spring JPA api, like this: ""SELECT c FROM TagIncident c WHERE c.tagName =?1"" and it works alright, it is something about this specific query with view. I will test you way and tell you, I just need some time to test it, got some priorities before, thanks a lot! I will comment here when I do!